# How can I get byte array on nodejs and convert it to a file

Tags: node.js, express, fs

I am trying to get a byte array from an android and then trying to convert it into a file. How do I do this? I am also using the express framework.

Comment: Can you provide more information? Are you posting the byte array to an api? What approach are you taking currently?

Comment: Hey, I am posting it to an api yes. I was wondering if i could just req.body.bytearray and then fs.createwritestream(bitearray)

Answer (score 1):

From your android app you will do something like this

```
String url = "http://yourserver/file-upload";
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath(),
        "yourfile");
try {
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);

    InputStreamEntity reqEntity = new InputStreamEntity(
            new FileInputStream(file), -1);
    reqEntity.setContentType("binary/octet-stream");
    reqEntity.setChunked(true); // Send in multiple parts if needed
    httppost.setEntity(reqEntity);
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
    //Do something with response...

} catch (Exception e) {
    // show error
}
```

On the node side I assume you are using express. You can do something like this

```
var fs = require('fs');
app.post('/file-upload', function(req, res) {
    // get the temporary location of the file
    var tmp_path = req.files.yourfile.path;
    // set where the file should actually exists - in this case it is in the "images" directory
    var target_path = './public/images/' + req.files.yourfile.name;
    // move the file from the temporary location to the intended location
    fs.rename(tmp_path, target_path, function(err) {
        if (err) throw err;
        // delete the temporary file, so that the explicitly set temporary upload dir does not get filled with unwanted files
        fs.unlink(tmp_path, function() {
            if (err) throw err;
            res.send('File uploaded to: ' + target_path + ' - ' + req.files.yourfile.size + ' bytes');
        });
    });
};
```

Do a console.log(req.files) to have a look at what the android app is posting. Replace "yourfile" in req.files.**yourfile** with the correct property.